# Passing a dynamic variable to a function in c#

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to create a rather simple program with my own custom graphing code. One of the functions should be for the user to have the ability to change which data is being shown on the graph at any time through a drop down menu.

In order to graph, I currently do a check through a massive switch tree to find out what the user has selected, and then for each selection pass the relevant List of data through to the draw_graph function.

For example:

```
switch (graphOneSourceIndex)
{
    case 0:
    {
        switch (graphOneDataIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                drawGraph(listOne, gridGraphObj1);
                break;
            case 1:
                drawGraph(listTwo, gridGraphObj1);
                break;
            // more cases follow
        }
    }
    // more cases follow
}
```

etc, for up to 32 different types in one of the sections I've built. This makes for some extremely tedious code to work with.

My question then, is if there's a way to dynamically change which variable is being passed to a function, for example if I could maybe just call drawGraph(userSelectedIndex, graphObj), and it would be able to figure out which data set to use based on that, instead of writing it out like this every step of the way. I've had a look around and haven't found anything that seems overly relevant.

Comment: Have a look at [strategy design pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=strategy+design+pattern+C#%23).

Comment: One way to go about this is to use indexing collections instead of hardcoding an index to control map, e.g. your switches. For example you'd place all your `listOne`, `listTwo` items into a `List<T> allLists` collection. With that your call would look something like `drawGraph(allLists[graphOneDataIndex], gridGraphOb1)` That indexes the `allLists` collection with selecting the list through a switch. You'd then do the same for each component you need to select. Many front frameworks, winforms, wpf, etc have collections of your controls already or allow you to bind a collection of controls etc.

Comment: You might be able to use a dictionary of <userSelectedIndex, List<T>> and select which dataset to use based on that selected index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activator.CreateInstance() with interfaces, something like this:

```
    public interface IDrawObject
    {
        void drawGraph(List<int> list);
    }
    public class DrawObject1 : IDrawObject
    {
        public void drawGraph(List<int> list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("object1.drawGraph()");
        }
    }
    public class DrawObject2 : IDrawObject
    {
        public void drawGraph(List<int> list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("object2.drawGraph()");
        }
    }
```

then, can be used like this:

```
    var id = graphOneDataIndex; //1 or 2 in this example
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var drawObject = (IDrawObject)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"DrawObject{id}"));
    drawObject.drawGraph(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, since your reference is an `int` and and index, you could store your lists all together in an array, ie `???[] lists` instead of `??? listOne`, `??? listTwo`, etc. You can then access the list you want via `lists[graphOneDataIndex]`